# Is it possible to export a tabpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is a rather dumb and stupid question. However, I would like to know if you could export a TabPage and all its controls into a file, then reimport them.

There is TabControl.Pages.Add(name); and TabControl.Pages.Remove(name);

But as I said I need it in the form of a file.

I know it would be possible with many hard hours of labor and sweat making a overly advanced decoder and emulating the c# code. But I want to know if there is a built in way.

Comment: In theory you could dynamically construct `TabPage` controls based on some serialized format which can be exported and imported, but that could be way too complex depending on your needs. I don't know of a native way to do this.

Comment: @DanWilson Do you think it would be possible to make a class library, make a loader for it, then invoke the form I want to add a tab page to and add it from the class library/plugin into the form? Might be crazy enough to work.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I've never attempted it, and there could be pitfalls depending on the complexity of your form, but it might work. It's similar to how third-party user controls work.

Comment: @DanWilson yeah, on my form there can be a class that gets called and controlled by the plugin, in the plugin it could send data to the plugin. I will tell you how this goes. I will make a test plugin system and I will be back here if I run into issues.